# animation in one direction

Tags: iphone, animation

i like to animate my image "finga" not centered but from left or right:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];                                  
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
finga.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2,1.5);
finga.animationDuration = 2;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you need to move the finga view off screen left or right (set the frame) prior to doing your animation.

Comment: no, i want that the finga does not zoom from the center of the image but from the left or right border toward left or right